# Client error: `POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, dropbox-api

I am trying to backup my database zip file to `Dropbox` from Laravel Application and I am getting the following error. [Complete Log Link](https://airshop.pk/log.txt)

```
Client error: `POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized
```

[image]

I am using [A flysystem driver for Dropbox](https://github.com/spatie/flysystem-dropbox)

On the other hand, It's working fine on `Cpanel` but not working on Local `XAMPP` installation based on windows.

Comment: Seems like the API user account you're using on dropbox doesn't have the necessary privileges or scope defined.

Comment: `"required_scope": "files.metadata.read"`- the access token you are using does not include the mentioned permission.

Comment: @ADyson The issue is only with the localhost if it's the issue from the API then it should not work on Cpanel as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: It depends if you're using the exact same credentials and code in each case. Either way, the error message is not lying to you, so you need to put aside your assumptions and go and investigate it

Comment: @CBroe Permission is already granted for the access token,

Comment: @ADyson You are right :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you have enabled all the required permissions then I think this is very likely you have only one user allowed to access the API. Just click on `Link Users` from the `settings tab` to allow more `development users` to the API.

[image]

After that click on Regenerate Access token button and use that token.

Comment: Thanks for your answer let me try your solution if it works.

Comment: Thanks Sameer it's working now :-)

Comment: @LynRobert I am glad that my solution works for you. peace